# Difference between declarative label declarations?

Tags: asp.net

What is the difference between:

```
<asp:Label id="label1" runat="server" Text="label"></asp:Label>
```

and

```
<asp:Label id="label1" runat="server">label</asp:Label>
```

The same question can be applied to something like a ListItem for a DropDownList as well such as:

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Item" runat="server"></asp:ListItem>
```

as opposed to

```
<asp:ListItem runat="server">Item</asp:ListItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Label MSDN Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.aspx) says that the "Text" field is simply the [ControlValuePropertyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlvaluepropertyattribute.aspx), meaning inner content is bound to that Property.

This [ListItem MSDN Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) shows a matrix on how it handles the inner content.